# Upgrade nodejs in Ubuntu 22 failed

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, package, apt-get

```
nodejs -v
v12.22.9
```

I tried to upgrade

```
sudo apt remove nodejs
sudo apt install nodejs
```

I got error:

```
(Reading database ... 220599 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_21.6.1-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (21.6.1-1nodesource1) ...


dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_21.6.1-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/node/common.gypi', which is also in package libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_21.6.1-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
```

How can I resolve that so I can upgrade my nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/tj/n to install and manage nodejs version. You can install using curl:

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tj/n/master/bin/n | bash -s lts
```

and then you can do:

```
n latest
```

This will install the latest version. for specific version you can run:

```
n <version_number>
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing Node.js Using NVM (Node Version Manager)

NVM is a script-based version manager for Node.js, allowing you to install and manage multiple active Node.js versions. To install NVM, use the following commands:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash

export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

After installing NVM, you can install the latest version of Node.js with:

```
nvm install node
```

Verify the installation with:

```
node -v
```